# Coding method, why !== false

Tags: php

Why do I see people doing `if (false !== $var) {` instead of `if (false === true) {`

Comment: Because `false === true` is always false.

Comment: If you see `if (false === true)` in a webpage, most likely one of both was generated by a server-side script.

Comment: you are right about `false === true` always beeing false, but whats that mean?

Comment: Also because `$var` is a variable and `true`, well, isn't…

Comment: It's an elaborate way of saying `if(false)`

Comment: Did you mean `false !== $var` versus `$var === true` by any chance?

Comment: @Konerak: But if you see it *in* server-side code...

Comment: @Rocket: it's probably generated by something **enterprisy** (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer consists of three parts:

1. The difference in order between (false == $var) and ($var == false)
2. The difference between == and ===
3. Why you see people doing `(false !== $var)`  instead of `if (false === true)`

### 1. The difference in order between (false == $var) and ($var == false)

Because an often-made mistake is forgetting to put two `=` which results in an accidental attribution instead of comparison, some programmers decide to always put the invariable part of the equation on the left-side. This way, the **accidental assignment is impossible** and you don't risk getting

`if ($var = false)`

which assigns false to the variable `$var` and will always evaluate false instead of the desired

`if ($var == false)`

### 2. The difference between == and ===

The `===` or `!==` compares the variable's **type as well as its value**, whereas `==` and `!=` compare value and convert types where needed.

Example:

```
0 == false // true
1 == true // true

0 === false // false
1 === true // false

0 !== false // true
0 !== true // true

false === false // true
false === true  // false
```

`$var !== FALSE` is used because a lot of built-in PHP functions return `FALSE` on error, and a value on success.  The value returned may be the same value as `TRUE` but it may not be the same type.

### 3. Why you see people doing `(false !== $var)`  instead of `if (false === true)`

Your question itself made people snicker (that's why OrangeDog's comment was upvoted that much): if people did `if (false === true)`, it would equal `if(false)` and **would never execute the enclosing block**. It still happens though, for example in JavaScript when part of the code is generated in a serverside-language, like PHP.

Comment: We really need one answer that combines all three aspects of the answer: why the changed order, why the triple-instead-of-double, and why `$var` is not true (ok, trivial)

Comment: /me proudly stares at the edited answer and thinks we should put this as the StackOverflow homepage of the day.

Answer (score 0):

because its something completely different.

the first code part opens an if clause only if var is not false. it may be zero, null or an empty string. but not of type boolean and false.

the second one is a contradiction that can never ever happen.

Answer (score 0):

Why do I see people doing `if (false !== $var) {`

Logic comparisons are a common foil for beginning programmers, and it is typical to see
`$var = false`
when what was meant
`$var == false`

So standard practice is to encourage programmers to always place variables on the right hand side, since `$var=true` is technically legal, but produces unexpected behavior, while `true=$var` is not legal and throws an error.

In your case it looks like ugly, if sensible, programming habits were taken to their logical end.